# Как преобразовать список из одного элемента в строку?

Tags: python, строки, список

У меня есть список ['Рандомное слово']

Мне надо преобразовать этот список в строку.
На выходе должно получиться:

> Рандомное слово

Без всяких кавычек и скобочек.

```
''. join() Не работает
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Что значит "На выходе должно получиться"? Что вы делаете? (Нужен код в вопросе). Что получается? (Нужен пример в вопросе) Что вы хотите видеть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а как по мне - все работает

```
data = ['Рандомное слово']
text = ''.join(data)
print(text) # выводится Рандомное слово
```

второй вариант:

```
import re

keys = re.findall(r'равно(.*?)отправить', 'равно 12 отправить равно 100 отправить')
keys = ''.join(keys)

print(keys) # выводится  12  100
```

Comment: с регулярками это работает? Просто после проведения выражения, вернулся массив, но при преобразовании в строку ничего не произошло

Comment: а как именно вы хотите использовать регулярки?

Comment: `keys = str(re.findall(r'равно(.*?)отправить',message.text))` 
       
`keys = ''.join(keys)` 
       
`value = str(re.findall(r'текст(.*?);',message.text))` 
       
`value = ''.join(value)`

Comment: а накой вы в строку результат то переводите? :)
в своем ответе привел код под вашу ситуацию

Comment: Смотрите, это телеграмм бот, в лс боту, я должен писать текст, он этот текст берёт и взаимодействует.

Comment: второй приведенный пример не устраивает? не работает?

Comment: о, спасибо большое

Comment: Смотрите, всё работает, я сохраняю эту строку в переменную keys, и в телеграмм боте, ставлю условие - если сообщение равно keys, то отправить сообщение "hello", но если в лс боту, я напишу вот эту строку(которая сохранена в keys), то бот не отвечает. Я думаю это из-за того, что после "".join(), в строке появляется два пробела: один перед словом, другой после слова. Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: да не должны пробелы появляться
а почему вы не сравниваете просто с первым элементом `keys`? `if keys[0] = '...'`

Comment: всё равно не реагирует на сообщение пользователя

Comment: а у вас есть вк или тг?

Comment: тут нужно скрин показать

Comment: а всё, я решил проблему